# Laravel hasManyThrough returning empty array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database, has-many-through

I need some help regarding hasManyThrough()

**user_duty**

```
id

user_id

date

duty_hours
```

**sales_duty**

```
id

user_id

date

total_sales

total_orders
```

**income_table**

```
id

sales_id (this is same as 'id' of sales_duty)

date (same as 'date' of sales_duty)

total_income

total_collection
```

I can relate **sales_duty** with **income_table** using (**sales_id,date**) these two keys.

I can also connect to **sales_duty** from **user_duty** based on (**user_id,date**)

Now I want to connect to **user_duty** to **income_table**

```
public function user_income()

{

       return $this->hasManyThrough('App\IncomeTable','App\SalesTable','id','sales_id','id','id');

}
```

But its returning empty

Answer (score 2):

According to the details you have provided it should be like this.

```
public function user_income()
{
     return $this->hasManyThrough(
          'App\IncomeTable',
          'App\SalesTable',
          'user_id', // Foreign key on sales_duty table...
          'sales_id', // Foreign key on income_table...
          'id', // Local key on user_duty table...
          'id' // Local key on sales_duty table...
     );
}
```